# Download SQL Server 2012 Developer Edition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Does anyone know where you can download SQL Server 2012 Developer Edition, or purchase a licence for it?

I'm **NOT** talking about SQL Server 2014+ Developer edition, which is free. I need SQL Server 2012, as that is what our production server is.

Thanks all.

Comment: That page does NOT have developer. It has evaluation, which is not the same. A quick Ctrl+F "Developer" would have shown you that. :)

Comment: https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=SQL%20Server%20Developer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can head to downloads section in your Visual Studio Subscription portal. As seen, no key required.

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid the developer edition is not available anymore. Retail price used to be ~70$ but it does not seem to be available on MS Store.
They offer the Evaluation version and Express is also available.
I think this is because the developer is for free with 2016 version.